# Solr 4.4.0 is giving error code 500

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

Solr 4.4.0 is giving this error
can anyone help me??

```
HTTP Status 500 - {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Unable to use updateLog: _version_field must exist in schema, using indexed="true" stored="true" and multiValued="false" (_version_ does not exist),trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Unable to use updateLog: _version_field must exist in schema, using indexed="true" stored="true" and multiValued="false" (_version_ does not exist)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:860)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:251)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to use updateLog: _version_field must exist in schema, using indexed="true" stored="true" and multiValued="false" (_version_ does not exist)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:835)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:629)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:622)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:657)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:364)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:356)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ... 1 more Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to use updateLog: _version_field must exist in schema, using indexed="true" stored="true" and multiValued="false" (_version_ does not exist)
at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog.init(UpdateLog.java:267)
at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.<init>(UpdateHandler.java:134)
at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.<init>(UpdateHandler.java:94)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.<init>(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:96)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:537)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createUpdateHandler(SolrCore.java:607)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:819) ... 13 more Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: _version_field must exist in schema, using indexed="true" stored="true" and multiValued="false" (_version_ does not exist)
at org.apache.solr.update.VersionInfo.getAndCheckVersionField(VersionInfo.java:56)
at org.apache.solr.update.VersionInfo.<init>(VersionInfo.java:82)
at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog.init(UpdateLog.java:264) ... 23 more ,code=500}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solr 4.x provides a realtime get feature. For this to work it writes an update log which requires a _version field to be defined.

Add this in the `<fields> tag in schema.xml`

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

OR comment out this from your solrconfig.xml

```
  <requestHandler name="/get" class="solr.RealTimeGetHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="omitHeader">true</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="indent">true</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Remember if you comment out the /get request handler you won't get real time get and also miss out on Optimistic Concurrency ( explained here - http://yonik.com/solr/optimistic-concurrency/ )

Comment: Not sure if this is specific to using Sunspot, but the [field definition](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_solr/solr/solr/conf/schema.xml#L241) is a little different when using it: `<field name="_version_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />`

Answer (score 0):

Proper lines to comment out in order to fix this issue are:

    `<updateLog>
      <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
    </updateLog>`

P.S.
I know this is old, but still gets into the top 10 on google search.